# Ascii code outputting ?. Need a solution

Tags: c++, file-io, menu

Hey i want to output some ascii characters in a text file and then load them in and use them for a menu.  Can anyone help me on how to do this.  Here is my code:

```
#include "MenuText.h"
#include <iostream>//To allow the use of Header files.
#include <fstream>//To allow the use of external .txt files.
using namespace std;
using std::cout;

MenuText::MenuText()
{
    mText = "Default";

}
MenuText :: MenuText(string text)
{
mText = text;
}
void MenuText::print()
{
cout<< "Story= " << mText<< endl;
cout<< endl;
}
void MenuText::save(ofstream& outFile)
{
outFile<<   "┏┳┳┳┳┳┳┳┳●●●●●●━┓ ┣╋╋╋╋╋╋╋┫●●●●●●●┃\n" 
            "┣┻┻┻┻┻┻┻┻━━−●●●●┃ ┃Marooned ™ ●●●●┏┫\n "
            "┣┳┳┳┳┳┳┳┳−●●●●┏╋┫ ┣╋╋╋╋╋╋╋┫●●●●−┻┻┫\n" 
            "┣╋╋╋╋╋╋╋┫●●●●●●●┃ ┗┻┻┻┻┻┻┻┻●●χ " << mText<< endl;
cout<< endl;
outFile<< endl;
}
void MenuText::load(ifstream& inFile)
{
string garbage;
inFile>> garbage >> mText;
}



void MenuText::Menu()
{
cout<< "\n\t******Menu******\n\n";
cout<< "Please choose one of the following:\n";
cout<< "1 -Play Game.\n";
cout<< "2 -Exit.\n";

}
void MenuText::text()
{
ifstream text;                                                                                                     
        string line;                                                                                                            
        text.open("Text.txt");                                                                                        
        if (text.is_open())                                                                                
        {
                while ( text.good() )                                                                              
                {
                        getline (text,line);                                                                       
                        cout << line << endl;
                }
                text.close();                                                                                           
        }
        else{
                throw("The text file did not load.......!!!");                                                             
        }
}
```

Comment: Those are not ASCII characters. Read up what ASCII is and then come back here.

Comment: @KerrekSB when i first ran the program with these characters in it.  t said that they were ASCII

Comment: @Pendo826: They're actually Unicode.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First search for the ASCII/UNI code for **each character** and then use those code numbers to create a **char*** or **char[]** string/array. After that you can use this string how you want.
e.g.

```
char str[5]={125,124,126,122,121};
```

[Here](http://www.asciitable.com/) is the link for these codes...